# Menu não altera a largura

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

Estou fazendo um `menu vertical` e colocando a cor **preta** como background. O que estou passando é que quero deixar uma largura fixa de uns `200px` para cada linha do menu, só que ele não altera. Ele deixa o tamanho de acordo com o tamanho do texto.

**Código HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-3">

      <img src="" border="0" class="img-responsive">

      <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">A empresa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nossos serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nossos produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Vídeos & Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Fale conosco</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li{
  display: block;
  margin-top:25px;
  float:none;
}

ul li a{
  background:#000;
  padding:10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tratando o `background` dentro do elemento `a`. Faça dessa forma:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li{
    background:#000;
    display: block;
    margin-top:25px;
    float:none;
    padding:10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Se quiser personalizar especificadamente os links, daí sim você cria uma chamada no css para eles por meio do elemeno `a`:

```
ul li a{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: deu certo, me salvou. Obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. De nada [: